# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Enable WL.Logger.debug in Worklight Development Server Console

Tags: eclipse, logging, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Is there any way to enable WL.Logger.debug log to be displayed in Worklight Development Server Console view in eclipse?

I am using Worklight 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not.
See my explanation from this question: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to enable/view WL.Logger.debug in adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493912/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-enable-view-wl-logger-debug-in-adapters)

---

**Copy/paste:**

WebSphere Liberty profile does not support debug level logging in the Worklight Development Server Console view.

You can use `WL.Logger.debug` and edit `server.xml` to view the log in the `trace.log` file

1. Open the Servers view in Eclipse
2. Expend the Worklight Development Server entry
3. Double-click on Server Configuration (server.xml)
4. Switch to Source tab
5. Uncomment this line: `<logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=debug=enabled"/>`
6. After invoking your adapter procedure you will find the log at `<eclipseWorkspace>\WorklightServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs\trace.log`

Be sure to re-deploy the adapter before attempting to view the logs.

Alternatively,
You can use `WL.Logger.warn` or `WL.Logger.error`; these logs *will* display in the Worklight Development Server Console view.

Comment: I have read that, but can't we enable debug log in console view, because I am migrating my project from 5.0.6 to 6.1

Comment: Are you sure you read it? I wrote "... does not support debug level logging". So what's the question? You can't enable it.

Comment: Yes I have seen it. I think there should be some trick to enable it. Because 5.0.6 show the debug level log.

Comment: 506 did not use Liberty. 6.0 does, and in Liberty you cannot use debug level.

Comment: What about WL.Logger.info, will it displayed in console or not?

Comment: WL.Logger.info will show up in the console if you set that level in server.xml.

Comment: Hi Idan, can you let me know what are the other options example for info can i specify as <logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=info=enabled"/>, Will that work ?