# Where does Workligh server log the adapter calls when the log level is set to "debug"

Tags: logging, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

We have Worklight enterprise version 6.2.0.1, we were logging the adapters calls using "info"level like (WL.Logger.info("..")) and the log goes to Systemout.log file.

However, we changed the log level to "debug" like (WL.Logger.debug ("..")).

Where does the WL server save the debug logs? what is the file name and the path for this file? I don't think it is the same as Systemout.log, but I might be wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Enable WL.Logger.debug in Worklight Development Server Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141157/ibm-worklight-6-1-enable-wl-logger-debug-in-worklight-development-server-conso)

WebSphere Liberty profile does not support debug level logging in the Worklight Development Server Console view.

You can use `WL.Logger.debug` and edit `server.xml` to view the log in the `trace.log` file

1. Open the Servers view in Eclipse
2. Expend the Worklight Development Server entry
3. Double-click on Server Configuration (server.xml)
4. Switch to Source tab
5. Uncomment this line: `<logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=debug=enabled"/>`
6. After invoking your adapter procedure you will find the log at `<eclipseWorkspace>\WorklightServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs\trace.log`

Be sure to re-deploy the adapter before attempting to view the logs.

Comment: What I'm talking about is Enterprise server, not development, our server.xml file doesn't contain the line that you suggested to be uncomment. I believe I need to set this in WAS console in the following path (Troubleshooting>Logging and tracing > server11_was > Change log detail levels) > (Runtime tab)and add the following line (*=info,  com.worklight.*=debug=enabled) Am I right?

Comment: You can also just add the line. Should work the same.

Comment: This is the only line I have in server.xml, Would you please modify it to me to answer my question: <services xmi:type="traceservice:TraceService" xmi:id="TraceService_1404843241202" enable="true" startupTraceSpecification="*=info" traceOutputType="SPECIFIED_FILE" traceFormat="BASIC" memoryBufferSize="8">

Comment: I believe you should simply add another line to your server.xml - the one from my answer.