# console.log in worklight procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, console.log

my procdure in sql adapter is given below

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from userreg ");
function procedure1() {
var resp= WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
    parameters : []
});


    var a=resp.resultSet;
    var name=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){

         name[i]=a[i].name;

    }
    //return (name);
    //alert (name);

    console.log( name.toString());
}
```

if i call this procedure can i display name values in browser console,

or if i use WL.logger.log() instead of console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use console.log in server-side code... you must have code **in the client-side** that will receive the response from this server-side code (that is - you must return it), and *then* you could use console.log (and other options) - in the client-side - to print the values to the *console* in your browser or LogCat or other tools...

What you can do in the case of adapter logging or debugging, is to use `WL.Logger.warn` or `WL.Logger.error` to print out to the *Eclipse console*.

See this question for more information on the above: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to enable/view WL.Logger.debug in adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493912/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-enable-view-wl-logger-debug-in-adapters)