# ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice starting Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am starting Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0 where I have hosted some WEb applications, but I can not start it because I have an error

echo starting weblogic with Java version:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% -version

if "%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%"=="" (
    echo Starting WLS with line:
    echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
) else (
    echo Redirecting output from WLS window to %WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%  >"%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%" 2>&1 
)
```

but i got this error:

```
C:\myprograms\Tools\tracesnt>startWebLogic.cmd
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
.
CLASSPATH=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\lib\tools.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar
;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_1.0.0.0.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\com.oracle.cie.config-wls-online_8.1.0.0.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derby.jar;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\native\win\32;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\bin;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\bin;C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\myprograms\Oracle\product\112~1.0\CLIENT~1\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\
v1.0\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\myprograms\ZANTAZ\EASOUT~1.2\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MIE3C7~1;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~1\TORTOI~1\bin;C:\myprograms\APACHE~2.3\bin;C:\TD\TD_RF_~1.0\gnu\bin;C:\myprograms\WLSTAP~1.2\bin;C:\myprograms\PHANTO~1.0-W;C:\myprograms\RUBY-2~1.2-X\bin;C:\myprograms\RUBY-2~1.3-X;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK17~1.0_7\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\QUICKT~1\QTSystem\;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=myserver -Djava.security.policy=C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Dweblogic.domain.home=C:\myprograms\Tools\tracesnt -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2500,server=y,suspend=n -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Xverify:none -Djava.
endorsed.dirs=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\endorsed  -da -Dwls.home=C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\myprograms\Tools\wls12130\wlserver\server     -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2500,server=y,suspend=n  weblogic.Server
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp

C:\myprograms\Tools\tracesnt>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you read the error message? Especially for this part **"check your java command line for duplicate jdwp"**. Then you might have found that `-Xrunjdwp` is twice in the startup command (the line below: "Starting WLS with line").

So you need to check where the values for `%JAVA_OPTIONS%` and `%PROXY_SETTINGS%` are set in your startup configuration. I guess `-Xrunjdwp` is appended twice to `%JAVA_OPTIONS%` (except someone has misused `%PROXY_SETTINGS%`).

Comment: It took me some time to figure out, so I'll add this for others like me who aren't so familiar with tomcat : The Java Options is a part of the Tomcat configuration, in the Java tab. I did not found the Proxy Settings though, but I really had line duplicated in the Java option, that appeared for reasons unknown to me since it was working before and didn't modified myself.... anyway thanks for that answer!

Comment: @Rafiki Interesting that WebLogic and Tomcat are affected by the same problem. Are you also using Windows? Do you remember what you did before it stopped working as before? Something like a Java update.

Comment: Yes, on Windows server 2012. And no I did not do anything special before, or so I think. It just stopped working one day. The I probably *did* something, but I have no idea what