# Environment variable set twice by docker-compose up command

Tags: docker-compose, corda

I have defined a environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in my yaml file. When I start up my containers with the command "docker-compose -f  up" I get the following error:

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8010,server=y,suspend=n
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8010
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8010,server=y,suspend=n
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp

It looks like the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is set twice. Any help will be very much appreciated

Below is my .yaml file:

```html
version: '3.1'
services:

  blumeglobal:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: corda-3.2
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10003:10003"
      - "10004:10004"
      - "10005:10005"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: blumeglobal
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/BlumeGlobal/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  bestbuy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10012:10002"
      - "10013:10003"
      - "10014:10004"
      - "10015:10015"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: bestbuy
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/Bestbuy/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  expeditors:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8010,server=y,suspend=n
    ports:
      - "10022:10002"
      - "10023:10003"
      - "10024:10004"
      - "10025:10025"
      - "8010:8010"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: expeditors
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/Expeditors/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  motorcarrier:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10032:10002"
      - "10033:10003"
      - "10034:10004"
      - "10035:10035"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: motorcarrier
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/DTDC/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  one:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10042:10002"
      - "10043:10003"
      - "10044:10004"
      - "10045:10045"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: one
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/ONE/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  cisco:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10052:10002"
      - "10053:10003"
      - "10054:10004"
      - "10055:10055"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: cisco
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/Cisco/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  foxconn:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10062:10002"
      - "10063:10003"
      - "10064:10004"
      - "10065:10065"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: foxconn
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/Foxconn/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  toshiba:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
    ports:
      - "10072:10002"
      - "10073:10003"
      - "10074:10004"
      - "10075:10075"
    image: corda:3.2
    container_name: toshiba
    volumes:
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence.mv.db
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/additional-node-infos/:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos/
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
      - ./build/nodes/Toshiba/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    depends_on:
      - blumeglobal
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```html
FROM openjdk:8u151-jre-alpine

# Override default value with 'docker build --build-arg BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION=version'
# example: 'docker build --build-arg BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION=1.0.0 -t corda/node:1.0 .'
ARG BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION=3.2-corda
ARG BUILDTIME_JAVA_OPTIONS

ENV CORDA_VERSION=${BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION}
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=${BUILDTIME_JAVA_OPTIONS}

# Set image labels
LABEL net.corda.version = ${CORDA_VERSION} \
      maintainer = "<blockchainservice@infosys.com>" \
      vendor = "infosys"

RUN apk upgrade --update && \
    apk add --update --no-cache bash iputils && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    # Add user to run the app && \
    addgroup corda && \
    adduser -G corda -D -s /bin/bash corda && \
    # Create /opt/corda directory && \
    mkdir -p /opt/corda/plugins && \
    mkdir -p /opt/corda/logs

# Copy corda jar
ADD --chown=corda:corda https://dl.bintray.com/r3/corda/net/corda/corda/${CORDA_VERSION}/corda-${CORDA_VERSION}.jar                       /opt/corda/corda.jar

COPY run-corda.sh /run-corda.sh
RUN chmod 777 /opt/corda && chmod +x /run-corda.sh && \
    sync && \
    chown -R corda:corda /opt/corda

# Expose port for corda (default is 10002) and RPC
EXPOSE 10002
EXPOSE 10003
EXPOSE 10004
EXPOSE 10005 10015 10025 10035 10045 10055 10065 10075

# Working directory for Corda
WORKDIR /opt/corda
ENV HOME=/opt/corda
USER corda

# Start it
CMD ["/run-corda.sh"]
```

Comment: I see your pointing it to a dockerfile, do you have environment variables defined there as well?

Comment: Yes I do. But not the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable. Below is my Dockerfile

Comment: I have edited my question and added my Dockerfile

Comment: So looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352006/error-cannot-load-this-jvm-ti-agent-twice-starting-oracle-weblogic-server-12-1). My guess is not the duplicate JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS but rather an argument specified within it or elsewhere that is coming up as a duplicate when you run the Java command

Comment: I am sure the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is read twice since the error output clearly says so

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. it is read twice, but setting an environment variable twice wouldn't cause any issue as it simply overrides the previous value. It sounds like there are multiple processes starting up with the same JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. For instance a run and a debug connection

Answer (score 0):

Try another base java image for your dockerfile. (e.g. 'FROM azul/zulu-openjdk:8u192')

Here's an example of what you're trying to do which you can find here: https://github.com/EricMcEvoyR3/corda-docker-compose (you'll notice he doesn't even set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variables)

You'll also want to note there's a dockerform task in Corda to generate the task for you: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/generating-a-node.html#the-dockerform-task

It looks like you're copying over the correct information in the dokcer-compose file, just take another look at these examples and see if you're able to get this to work.

best of luck on the adventure of building blockchain.