# Turn Off Worklight server logging from server.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I know that I can turn off the logging on server.xml for the developer edition.

But we are running WL enterprise 6.2.0.1, where can I find the server.xml to turn off the adapters logging.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this has to do with your project specifically.

In the application server's server.xml (if you followed the deployment instructions for Worklight projects [as provided in the Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/topics/c_deploy.html)) you should have an entry specifying your Worklight project.

In this same file, you need to configure the logging level for `com.worklight`.
See here: [Logging mechanisms](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/admin/r_logging_and_monitoring_mechanisms.html)

Maybe this will work:

```
<logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=info=disabled"/>
```

You need to play with it per the WebSphere documentation (as it is not related to Worklight per-se).

Related question (you need to do the opposite of the written in the answer): [IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to enable/view WL.Logger.debug in adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493912/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-enable-view-wl-logger-debug-in-adapters)

Comment: Inside the .war file, there is no file called server.xml, I have validated it by unzipping the file. what is "wlp"? can you give more specific location for it?

Comment: we don't have directory "servers" under "usr", the only server.xml we have is for the whole environment, not for our project. The server.xml that we have is controlling the full node for our environment (WAS).

Comment: I can't change the server.xml that provided in the location that mentioned in the URL since it controls the logs for everything. and assuming there is a parameter I can change to turn off the logs for our application, then which one is it?

Comment: See my updated answer again; you need to configuring the logging level for com.worklight.

Comment: The documentation in the Logging mechanisms are not functional,when I click on them being directed to the main knowledge centre.

Comment: The link for WAS 8.5.5 works, it will be the same procedure. BTW, can you further expend on what you're trying to hide exactly?

Comment: In our adapters, we have WL.Logger.info, this API is logging the user credentials on the server log (Systemout.log), I need to disable the logger without deleting (WL.Logger.Info) from the adapters. On the WL developer edition, we can set the level of log to be (OFF, AUDIT,INFO....), need to do the same on WL enterprise 6.2.0.1 for our application.

Comment: we need to test this change and what does impact on the rest of the runtimes. will update you with the test soon, thanks