# how to debug IBM worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Hi I am trying to debug the worklight adapter and couldn't find any solution. firebug is also not showing the adapter and also i am not able to put an alert in the adapter to check. can someone say how can I debug the worklight adapter as I need to know where the error in adapter is

Answer (score 1):

- If you have implemented a JavaScript adpater (Worklight/MFP 6.x, 7.0) then you can debug JavaScript adapters as mentioned in the following answer: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to enable/view WL.Logger.debug in adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493912/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-enable-view-wl-logger-debug-in-adapters)

  You cannot place alerts in an adapter because it uses server-side JavaScript and is outside of the application scope. In other words, alerts make no sense as they have no place to print to. See the above answer to learn how to print logs to the server.
- If you have implemented a Java adapter (MFP 7.0 only) then you can debug it as described in the following tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/debugging-adapters/